# Converting TimeStamp to readable time ago in PHP and Android

Tags: php, android, json

I am sending the data from server to android and I have a field as timestamp in the database and also I send data as JSON but when I send the data it shows the date like this : date":1463232118" or when I remove 'strtotime' function from the code it shows the date like this : 2016-05-18 10:24:32 but when I put 'strtotime' out side JSON array that is going to be sent to android side and I open it in browser it shows like this : 4 weeks ago or 3 days ago and it is correct but when I send it as JSON array it shows this : date":1463232118". This is my complete PHP code guide me please or add something you know

```
<?php

require_once("include.php");

$tbl_name ="ads";
$order_by ="id";

$records_limit= 6;


$connect = @mysqli_connect($hostname , $username , $password , $database);

if( $connect )
{
    @mysqli_query($connect , "SET CHARACTER SET utf8;");

    $temp1 = @mysqli_query($connect , "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM".$tbl_name);

    $temp2 = @mysqli_fetch_row($temp1);

    $total_records = $temp2[0];

    if(isset( $_GET['page']))
    {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
        $offset = $page * $records_limit;
    }
    else
    {
        $page = 0;
        $offset = 0;
    }

    $my_query = "SELECT * FROM ".$tbl_name." ORDER BY ".$order_by." DESC LIMIT ".$offset.",".$records_limit;

    $result = @mysqli_query($connect , $my_query);
    if( $result )
    {
        $response['ads'] = array();
        $response['success'] = 1;  


        while( $row = @mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
        {
            $ads = array();

            $curenttime=$row['date'];
            $time_ago =strtotime($curenttime);

            $ads['id']  = $row['id'];
            $ads['title']   = $row['title'];    
            $ads['intro']   = $row['intro'];
                    $ads['image']   = $sitename . $row['image'];
            $ads['seller']  = $row['seller'];
            $ads['phone']   = $row['phone'];

            $ads['date']    = $time_ago;

            $q = "SELECT name FROM cat WHERE id='".$row['cat_id']."'";
            $temp1 = @mysqli_query($connect , $q);
            $temp2 = @mysqli_fetch_row($temp1);
            $cat = $temp2[0];


            $ads['cat'] = $cat;         

            array_push( $response['ads'] , $ads);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $response['success'] = 0;
        $response['message'] = "nothing";
    }

    echo(json_encode($response)); 


    @mysqli_close( $connect );
}



function timeAgo($time_ago){

$cur_time   = time();
$time_elapsed   = $cur_time - $time_ago;
$seconds    = $time_elapsed ;
$minutes    = round($time_elapsed / 60 );
$hours      = round($time_elapsed / 3600);
$days       = round($time_elapsed / 86400 );
$weeks      = round($time_elapsed / 604800);
$months     = round($time_elapsed / 2600640 );
$years      = round($time_elapsed / 31207680 );
// Seconds
if($seconds <= 60){
    echo "$seconds seconds ago";
}
//Minutes
else if($minutes <=60){
    if($minutes==1){
        echo "one minute ago";
    }
    else{
        echo "$minutes minutes ago";
    }
}
//Hours
else if($hours <=24){
    if($hours==1){
        echo "an hour ago";
    }else{
        echo "$hours hours ago";
    }
}
//Days
else if($days <= 7){
    if($days==1){
        echo "yesterday";
    }else{
        echo "$days days ago";
    }
}
//Weeks
else if($weeks <= 4.3){
    if($weeks==1){
        echo "a week ago";
    }else{
        echo "$weeks weeks ago";
    }
}
//Months
else if($months <=12){
    if($months==1){
        echo "a month ago";
    }else{
        echo "$months months ago";
    }
}
//Years
else{
    if($years==1){
        echo "one year ago";
    }else{
        echo "$years years ago";
    }
}
}

?>
```

The below is the output when I put   `$curenttime=$ads['date'];
                                $time_ago =strtotime($curenttime);
                                echo timeAgo($time_ago);` outside the array.

```
  5 hours ago5 hours ago4 days ago4 days ago4 days ago
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `timeAgo` function should `return` value instead of `echo`.

And you forgot to call `$ads['date'] = timeAgo($time_ago);` and that is why you have the `strtotime` value in your JSON instead of the converted value to ago.

**EDIT**

To return the value from your `timeAgo()` function simply do this:

```
return $seconds . " seconds ago";
```

Comment: how should I return Value instead of echo?

Comment: and I called $ads['date'] = timeAgo($time_ago); but it is showing date : null

Comment: did you return the ago value from the timeAgo function?

Comment: yes I did but and replaced your return value but it is returning 47 years ago

Comment: Yes you will get that value. Because you're logic is such: dividing 1463232118 (the value you have in $time_now) / 31207680 (the value you are dividing with for year condition) will give you 46.88 something.

Comment: so what is the solution please tell me ?

Comment: What is the date stored in your database?